# How do I go about making a top menu/submenu system like this in Android?

Tags: android, menu, tabs

Example: http://cdn3.staztic.com/screenshots/cfo-magazine-mobile-1-2.jpg

I've just started learning how to program android apps, and I'm not sure how to go about it. Are they using tab layouts for both the main menu and the submenu right below it? If you could point me in the right direction, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use tabs and Listview together..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top menu is a [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

The "submenu" looks like a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) with [Buttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

The main view is a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a `LinearLayout` to act as the tab content's view something like this...

```
<LinearLayout>
    <!-- Usual width/height attributes and set the orientation as vertical -->
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- Usual width/height attributes and set the orientation as horizontal -->
        <!-- Place the 'Latest News' and other buttons here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView>
        <!-- Usual width/height attributes -->
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```